# Windows Service Interacting with Browser

Tags: c#, .net, windows, google-chrome, windows-services

I have a Windows service installed on user computers. The user logs into my website. How can I have the service pass an ID to my server when a user clicks a button on my website. There’s no log-in feature on the windows service.

The feature I am trying to create is my server executing a method on the client Windows service when they click a button on my website. But I need to know which machine to send the command to. The user could have multiple machines and I only want to execute the method on the machine they are currently using to browse the site. The user could be using any browser installed on their computer.

Basically, I want my website to be the UI for my Windows service. I’m not looking to install a GUI on the client computer.

I’m open to suggestions.

Comment: *"I’m no [sic] looking to install a GUI on the client computer"* - That's just not going to work. Browsers isolate the user from the rest of the system to prevent malware from taking root in the system. You're going to need something the user trusted enough to install on the system (which the browser can launch with the user's permission) to communicate with the Windows Service.

Comment: Start in windows service HTTP server, reserve port for example 54674 and in UI just navigate when button clicked to `http:://127.0.0.1:54674/api/SomeOperation`.

Comment: You installed the service somehow so why not also host the webserver (or a webserver) in that service? The API behind the website hosted by the server can still be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a generic windows client participating in a remote request and receiving back from a centralized server (host computer) some data. To provide you with implementation details (which it sounds like you are asking for) we will require more details on the specific technologies you plan on using on both the client and server.

Maybe it would help to look into **WCF** and **ASP.NET**.

Comment: The service is .NET the website/server is running .NET Core. The service and server have a connection using sockets.